# Problem previewing custom TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have created a custom view that encapsulates both `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText`.
The view seems to be rendered properly both on the emulator and a hardware device.
But when I open the preview panel in Android Studio the custom view does not render properly.

Here are the errors that I receive any tips are appreciated.

- `Couldn't resolve resource @string/path_password_strike_through`
- `<transition> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable`
- ```
  android.view.InflateException:  Can't morph from @string/path_password_eye_mask_strike_through to @string/path_password_eye_mask_visible
      at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.getPVH(AnimatorInflater.java:308)
      at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.parseAnimatorFromTypeArray(AnimatorInflater.java:422)
      at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:1053)
      at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadObjectAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:1011)
      at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:667)
      at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:642)
      at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:126)
      at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable.inflate(AnimatedVectorDrawable.java:565)
      at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1332)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1291)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1266)
      at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:330)
      at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:684)
      at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.parseTransition(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:473)
      at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:455)
      at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflate(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:385)
      at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1332)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1291)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1266)
      at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:330)
      at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getDrawable(Resources_Delegate.java:186)
      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:827)
      at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:626)
      at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
      at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
      at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
      at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
      at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:76)
      at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:344)
      at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:247)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:401)
      at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:184)
      at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:142)
      at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:229)
      at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:421)
      at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:432)
      at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:336)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
      at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:327)
      at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:386)
      at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
      at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:450)
      at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:590)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  ```

**Edited (added code sample)**

**Custom View:**

```
    public class MaterialTextInputView extends TextInputLayout {

      private TextInputEditText editText;

      public MaterialTextInputView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
      }

      public MaterialTextInputView(Context context, AttributeSet) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init(context);
      }

      public MaterialTextInputView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
      }

      private void init(Context context) {
        TextInputEditText editText = new TextInputEditText(getContext());
        editText.setId(ViewCompat.generateViewId());

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        this.editText = editText;

        addView(this.editText, params);
        setErrorEnabled(true);
      }
    }
```

**Example usage in xml:**

```
<com.marian.caloriecounter.ui.common.MaterialTextInputView
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="bar"
        style="@style/TextInputLayout"/>
```

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've declared the variable not being resolved like `string/path_password_strike_through` in String file and also the drawable in drawable folder

And it's quite ambiguous without a snap of your code...if you share that it'd be easy to help

Comment: I have added a sample implementation and how it is being used, the strange thing is that the missing resources are not referenced by my code.

Comment: I have the same error in my log of preview panel but it loads the preview quite fine, try force refreshing the layout and this seems to be a bug which is to fixed in next beta released a few days ago